# Suppose $L$ is a Lie algebra with abelian subalgebra $A$. Say that the $L$ module $V$ decomposes as a direct sum of weight spaces for $A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Suppose $L$ is a Lie algebra with abelian subalgebra $A$. Say that the $L$ module $V$ decomposes as a direct sum of weight spaces for $A$. Let $W$ be a $L$ submodule of $V$

Can somebody explain to my why each $a \in A$ acts diagonalisably on $V$ and preserves W?

Does the fact that $A$ acts diagonalisably on $V$ have anything to do with the fact that it is abelian? $V$ decomposes as a direct sum of weight spaces for $A$, but those weight spaces are not said to be 1 dimensional, which makes me think we might need to bring the fact that $A$ is abelian into the arguement. Thank you!

Comment: What, according to the definition you work with, is a weight space? Also, you know that an $L$-submodule is also an $A$-submodule?

Comment: A weight for a subalgebra $A$ of $L$ is a linear map $\lambda: A \rightarrow F$ and the weight space is $V_{\lambda}=\{v \in V$ such that $a(v) = \lambda(a)v$ for all $a \in A \}$

Comment: So for any basis of such a weight space, how would the matrix of an $a\in A$ acting on the weight space look like?